# Packages not listed while creating a class in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, package-explorer

I am facing a couple of issues in Eclipse and I feel they are related.

1. I cannot see the structure of packages in style package.subpackage1.subpackage2 but in the folder structure we see in windows explorer i.e.

    package

    |---   subpackage1

    |---subpackage2
2. While I try to create a class in a package , it is added to a default package and I cannot see a package as the packages are not listed.

[An illustration of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAuyV.png)

I checked perspectives as well - the issue persists in Java or JavaEE perspectives. I also changed the "Package Presentation" to "Hierarchical" but it wouldn't help.  I checked with Package Explorer as well as Project Explorer. I am using Photon Release (4.8.0).

I tried searching it on Google and here in StackOverflow too but found nothing relevant thus seeking help from the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put your Java class files into the source folder `src/main/resources` (where in Maven by default `.java` files will be ignored to be compiled) instead of into the source folder `src/main/java`.

Answer (score 0):

Problems seem to be that you do not have a source folder.
Right-click on your project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path

In Configure Build Path select Source tab. Add source folder src/main/java.
Create your packages and java files in this folder